# Retrieve photos in Facebook Message via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, message

I was trying to retrieve my own Facebook Messages and its photos.

I was able to use `/me/inbox` to retrieve list of conversations, then with `Thread /{thread-id}`, i was able to see the messages in the conversation.

What is interesting though is that for ever message that is a photo, there were no information of the photo included, it simply omitted the message key & value. I tried to access each individual message with `Message /{message-id}` endpoint, i would however get the following error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Looking to hearing from anyone with knowledge/experience to this issue. Thanks